# Entity Framework 4.1 - Code First - Cannot update nullabe DateTime values while resolving DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have an entity that I'm trying to edit through my MVC 3 web app.  I receive an `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`when trying to perform a the client wins approach I got from MSDN's post [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 9: Optimistic Concurrency Patterns](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/03/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-9-optimistic-concurrency-patterns.aspx). The weird part is that this only happens on this particular entity and there I'm not doing anything different from the other. Also, it only happens when updating from a null to a value. The Properties giving the error when updating from null value to a `DateTime` value are `DispositionLetterDate` and `DateDisposition`.

Class:

```
public class A22
{
    public A22()
    {
        this.IsArchived = false;
        this.A22StatusId = (int)AStatus.Open;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage="A22 Number cannot exceed 100 characters")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Manual")]
    public int ManualId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="SGMLID")]
    public string SGMLId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name="Date Received")]
    public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }

    [Display(Name= "Status")]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(A22Status))]
    public int A22StatusId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Priority")]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(A22Priority))]
    public int A22PriorityId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Providing Disposition")]
    public string ProvidingDisposition { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Final Disposition")]
    public bool FinalDisposition { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Is Archived")]
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Created By")]
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Date Created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    [Display(Name="Date Modified")]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Disposition Date")]
    public DateTime? DateDisposition { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Disposition Letter Sent")]
    public DateTime? DispositionLetterDate{ get; set; }

    // Virtual Properties

    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManualId")]
    public virtual Manual Manual { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<A22Manual> A22ManualsImpacted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<A22Task> A22TasksImpacted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<A22Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<A22HistoryLog> HistoryLogs { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(A22 a22)
{
    var d = new A22Repository().Find(a22.Id);
    var changes = TrackChanges(d, a22);
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(changes))
        {
            repository.InsertOrUpdate(a22);
            this.repository.AddHistory(a22, changes);
            repository.Save();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = a22.Id });
    } else {
        ViewBag.PossibleManuals = d.ManualId == default(int) ? manualRepo.GetManualList() :
                                                               manualRepo.GetManualList(d.ManualId);
        ViewBag.APriority = repository.GetAPriorityList(d.APriorityId);
        ViewBag.AStatus = repository.GetAStatusList(d.APriorityId);
        return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model TPMVC.Web.Models.A22

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BlendLayoutLeftOnly.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit A22# @Model.Number</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedById)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateCreated)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateModified)
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit")

    <div class="newItemLabel">
        <strong style="padding-right: 145px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AStatusId)</strong>
    @{
        Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
            .Name("AStatusId")
            .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AStatus)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width: 200px;" })
            .Render();
     }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AStatusId)
    </div>

    <div class="newItemLabel">
        <strong style="padding-right: 77px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FinalDisposition)</strong>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FinalDisposition)
    </div>

    <div class="newItemLabel">
        <strong style="padding-right: 44px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateDisposition)</strong>
        @{
          Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.DateDisposition)
            .Render();       
        }
    </div>

    <div class="newItemLabel">
        <strong style="padding-right: 44px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DispositionLetterDate)</strong>
       @{
           Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.DispositionLetterDate)
            .Render();       
        }
    </div>

    <div class="newItemLabel">
        <strong style="padding-right: 110px;">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsArchived)       </strong>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsArchived)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Thinking it was could have been something with the data annotations, I decided to define the properties with this issue to optional using the Fluid API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A22>().Property(a => a.DateDisposition).IsOptional();
modelBuilder.Entity<A22>().Property(a => a.DispositionLetterDate).IsOptional();
```

I basically need a fresh pair of eyes to see if I'm missing something. Is there other property that is making it behave this way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what database is mapped your EF configuration? MS SQL Server, MySQL, something else?

Comment: There is a bug that has to do with updating a nullable property from null to a value.  If you post the code for InsertOrUpdate I can tell you whether or not you are hitting it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm mapping nullable DateTime properties like following without IsOptional methods. Also it works fine with MS SQL and MySQL by me.

```
this.Property(t => t.CreatedDate).HasColumnName("CreatedDate");
this.Property(t => t.ModifiedDate).HasColumnName("ModifiedDate");
```

in class derived from EntityTypeConfiguration. I'm using Code First approach.